# Prevent chef from removing members from a group

Tags: chef

In my chef recipe I'm creating a group with

```
group "mygroup" do
  action :create
end
```

I have other users that are added and removed from the server which are not managed by chef. When I run chef client, any users that have been added to my group are removed from the group. I would think that since I'm not using append (it defaults to false) and not supplying a member list that it wouldn't try to manage the users.

Is there any way to prevent my new users from being removed from this group? Or to not run the group resource at all if the group has already been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `append` is `false` and `members` is `nil` which means: make sure this group has no members. You want `append` to be `true`.

Comment: Yep, that did it. If append is true and the member list is nil, the group is left as it was.